Why do my MFC dialogues not have an AutomationId?
I am using the Appium Windows Driver along with WinAppDriver to perform automated testing of an MFC application.
When viewed in the Inspect tool, my controls (buttons, edits, etc) have AutomationId values which correspond to their ID given in the resource.h file.
However, none of the dialogues have AutomationIds, and indeed I can't see a way to identify them at all. The tree-view looks something like this:

"My Application" window

"" dialogue

"" combo box
"" text
"" dialogue

"Button 1" button
"Checkbox 1" checkbox
"Edit 1" edit







This is causing a problem because there can be at any one time multiple dialogues with controls which share an AutomationId, because they have same name in the code. What I would want to do is select the parent dialogue then select the control within that dialogue.

Is there something I need to set or enable in Visual Studio when building my MFC executable?
Is there something else I can use to select these dialogues?

